# Notification of synchronization complete (iCLoud)

Tags: ios, icloud

How can I be notified that iCloud synchronization has been complete, how can i know that i have new data to show?
For example application has some data. Application has been deleted and reinstalled. When i open document with openWithCompletionHandler it calls my block before synchronization has been done.

Answer (score -1):

In viewDidLoad method,

```
//Catch any changes
  NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore *store = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(storeDidChange:)
                                                 name:NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification
                                               object:store]; 

    [[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] synchronize];
```

Implement the method,

```
- (void)storeDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Retrieve the changes from iCloud
    _notes = [[[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] arrayForKey:@"AVAILABLE_NOTES"] mutableCopy];
    
}
```

check this link also,
http://www.appcoda.com/icloud-programming-ios-intro-tutorial/

Comment: Thank you for answer. But it doesn't work for me. I think i need to observe something like NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification but it never fired. Why?